# PHP model with too many constructor arguments

Tags: php, design-patterns

In my current project I am implementing an Model-View-Presenter pattern. Most of my classes that represent domain objects have too many constructor arguments. Take this for example (NOTE: This is just a made-up class, just assume that models need too many arguments):

```
class Person {
    private $id;
    private $first_name;
    private $middle_name;
    private $last_name;
    private $birthdate;

    private $school_name;
    private $school_year_level;

    ... more properties

    public function __constructor($id, $first_name, $middle_name, $last_name, .. etc){
        ... some code to set the properties
    }
}
```

Suppose this class has many independent values needed for construction (7+ values), what good design can I use? The values are fetched rows from a database.

**EDIT**: To provide additional info, my model has three layers:

- **Models (Value Objects)**: Just a domain object with properties, and probably some methods for minimal processing of data.
- **Data Access Objects**: Communicates with the database. CRUD. Creates Model objects from fetched data.
- **Service Objects**: Provides an interface for the rest of the business logic interacts with data from the database.

Comment: Use the params in constructor that your object needs immediately at the instantation.. use setters for other params

Comment: Pass it an associative array?  Convert said assoc. array ot a JSON string and pass that?  Pass just an ID number or similar, do the sql query inside the class?

Comment: I am using a Data Access Object (Dao) for fetching data. It just dumps it into this class.

Comment: The answers so far here don't really solve your problem. They just move it somewhere else. If you use an array, then you still have to set all the values of the array. If you use an object, it's the same thing. In either case, you have the same number of arguments attached to one data structure.

The phrase that strikes me is "too many constructor arguments." How did you come to that conclusion? What's the threshold and why? It seems to me that if an object needs 7+ arguments to be defined, then you give it 7+ arguments. There's nothing wrong with that structure.

Comment: You could create a Name object, for example. Then the first, middle, and last name become one variable. But you're still ultimately moving the problem around. That takes three values and combines them into one. But elsewhere you're going to have to take that one value and break it back into three. So what have you really accomplished aside from adding unnecessary complexity? But I prefer procedural to OOP, so I'm biased.

Comment: So you have a DAO -- why don't you inject THAT object into this class? Then your constructor would be:                                                                                             public function __constructor(MyObject $myDAObject){
          ... (code to set props from your $myDAObject..)
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
public function __construct($params){
    $this->id = $params['id'];
    // etc ...
}
```

Or the [spread operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) if you are using **PHP 5.6+**:

```
public function __construct(...$params){
    $this->id = $params[0];
    // etc ...
}
```

If you are under **PHP 5.6** use [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

```
public function __construct(){
    $params = func_get_args();

    $this->id = $params[0];
    // etc ...
}
```

---

I would use the associative array solution because I prefer having the keys. Note that there are many other ways to solve your *"issue"* as @ivanivan said in his comment.

Comment: I guess I could use this solution since the models are just data handlers, practically associative arrays with a few methods. Isn't what I did bad design though?

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz there is no maximum arguments for constructors, this is more about readability. I guess that 7+ arguments would be considered *"bad design" in your case, yes. All of my solutions are tested. Feel free to accept my answer if you consider it answers your question :-)

Comment: Any suggestions on design? I'm kinda stuck with the poor database schema and some existing code that I must integrate with. Lucky me :)

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz As I said in the last paragraph of my answer, I would use the **associative array** solution. If you edit your question to show how you create a new object of this kind of class I could help you more. Good luck ;-)

Comment: I create it just like in the class constructor in my question. Anyway, using array as parameter seems like the better solution.

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz I meant to know how do you create a new instance of the class, when you do `$obj = new Person();`. This way I could guide you a bit if you want

Comment: The DAO makes them by passing values from the database.

Answer (score 1):

The best way in my opinion is try to passe an object to your constructor

```
public function __constructor(User $user)
```

Comment: Would you like to expand on why this will help, how $user itself will be constructed?

Comment: So then what about the user class? Doesn't this just move the problem that _that_ class?

Comment: passing a user object to a person object? does it really make sense? ;)

Comment: in the case of Person and User it's doesn't really make sense but its would help you can distract the object to many object like Address / User (auth properties) ...

Comment: My first idea is to group similar properties together as a separate class. It does somewhat provide abstraction and promote readability. But there are some cases where there is no other choice but to dump the data into the constructor.